# Deleting all non latin characters in a word file

Tags: microsoft-word, arabic

I have converted a pdf to .doc. In pdf there were Arabic letters and their explanation in latin. What I want to do is to delete all of those arabic characters (some of them didn't recognized by Adobe Pro) and just the latin letters remain.

Is there a way to do it?

Comment: Have you tried using `find and replace` command that most text editors have?

Answer (score 0):

Go to "Find and replace" check "use wildcards" and put  [!a-z A-Z 0-9 . , ? '] in the first box(you can add more punctuations there that you want to still be available). then click replace all with nothing at the second box. Basically this will delete all characters except the characters you put on the square brackets (which are latin letters, numbers, and punctuation).